# In Vim, how can I show or hide line numbers depending on the current file's extension?

Tags: vim, editor, vi

Vim can be configured to show line numbers by adding `set number` to your `.vimrc`.

How can I configure Vim to instead **only show or hide line numbers for certain file extensions**?

Examples:

- Show line numbers for all files except `.md` files
- Only show line numbers for `.rb`, `.js`, and `.vue` files

A `.vimrc`-based solution is probably preferable, but barring that, workarounds are welcome.

Comment: @PatrickBacon er, this isnt syntax. It’s a (local) option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's what you're looking for:

```
autocmd filetype markdown setlocal nonumber
```

for your first example, and

```
set nonumber
autocmd filetype ruby,javascript,vue setlocal number
```

Comment: You could probably use setlocal to make it even better